# Regex to find bad URLs in a database field

Tags: regex, validation

We had an issue with the text editor on our website that was doubling up the URL.  So for example, the text field may look contain:

```
This is a description for a media item, and here in <a href="http://www.example.com/apage.htmlhttp://www.example.com/apage.html">a link</a>.
```

So pretty much I need a regex to detect any string that begins with http and has another http before a closing quote, as in "http://www.example.com/apage.htmlhttp://www.example.com/apage.html"

Comment: You only want a match or want a capture of one of them?

Answer (score 3):

```
"http[^"]+http
```

Answer (score 1):

```
http://www.example.com/apage.htmlhttp://www.example.com/apage.html
```

This is actually a valid URL! So you'd want to be a bit careful not to munge any other URLs that happen to have ‘http://’ in the middle of them. To detect only a ‘doubled’ URL you could use backreferences:

```
"(https?://[^"]*)\1"
```

(This is a non-standard regex feature, but most modern implementations have it.)

Using regex to process HTML is a bad idea. HTML cannot reliably be parsed by regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the *.? syntax, you can just look for the following:

```
http(.*?)http
```

and if its present, reject the url.

Answer (score 0):

The string that begins with http and has another http before a quote is:

```
^http[^"]*http
```

But, although this answers exactly your question I suspect you may want Uh Clem's answer instead ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want something like this:

```
("http[^"]+)(http)
```

Then compare the two and if \1 === " + \2 then replace them.

One thought; do you have any query strings in any of your urls.  If you do, are any of them like this "http://someurl.com?http=somemoredatahttp://someurl.com?http=somemoredata"?

If so, you will want something far more complicated.